# Excel POI Unexpected missing row when some rows already present

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Someone have already seen this error ?

I get it just when I create my HSSFWorkbook

```
    try {

        LOGGER.info("Open Excel file: " + filename);
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
        Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

        /* save excel */
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filenameOutput);
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();

        wb.close();
        inputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e1.getMessage(), e1);
    }
```

error is on `new HSSFWorkbook(inputstream)`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected missing row when some rows already present
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet.setPropertiesFromSheet(HSSFSheet.java:212)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet.<init>(HSSFSheet.java:137)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:338)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:289)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:224)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:382)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:364)
```

Any idea ?

I have seen this question on http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/Unexpected-missing-row-when-some-rows-already-present-td5527417.html but they don't give good answer

I use POI 3.12

UPDATE : My excel contain 53 rows and hundreds columns so he is not empty. The excel was generated with **Buisness Object** and [some people have the very same issues](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47245) with no solution.

Source code of HSSFSheet is [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/poi/3.12/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I've found the solution.

Upgrade to 3.14 solve the problem.

The exception in 3.13 and previous is generated by [this code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/poi/3.12/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.java)

```
  RowRecord row = sheet.getNextRow();
  boolean rowRecordsAlreadyPresent = row != null;


207                 if (hrow == null) {
208                     // Some tools (like Perl module Spreadsheet::WriteExcel - bug 41187) skip the RowRecords
209                     // Excel, OpenOffice.org and GoogleDocs are all OK with this, so POI should be too.
210                     if (rowRecordsAlreadyPresent) {
211                         // if at least one row record is present, all should be present.
212                         throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected missing row when some rows already present");
213                     }
```

But on 3.14 [they just comment it](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/tags/REL_3_14_FINAL/src/java/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.java)

```
    if (hrow == null) {
        /* we removed this check, see bug 47245 for the discussion around this
        // Some tools (like Perl module Spreadsheet::WriteExcel - bug 41187) skip the RowRecords
        // Excel, OpenOffice.org and GoogleDocs are all OK with this, so POI should be too.
        if (rowRecordsAlreadyPresent) {
            // if at least one row record is present, all should be present.
            throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected missing row when some rows already present");
        }*/

        // create the row record on the fly now.
        RowRecord rowRec = new RowRecord(cval.getRow());
        sheet.addRow(rowRec);
        hrow = createRowFromRecord(rowRec);
    }
```

As they said, some tools skip the RowRec, in my case it's when i generate my .xls with **Buisness Object**

Answer (score 0):

example:

```
Workbook workbook = null;
try {
    workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(is);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

} catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
```

XSSF or HSSF doesn't matter, both should work well.

Comment: Provide more contents to support your answer, adding merely a code snippet doesn't seems to be a good answer.

Comment: think you ,my english is poor!